# What's the best way for a C# Desktop client to connect to a remote MySQL Db?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, web-services, apache

I am just learning c#, and am programming a Windows client that collects temperature data from the computer and needs to send it to a remote linux mySQL Database.

I was going to program it directly in the c# client, but I want to learn more ways to do this and gain experience. And programming it directly would be less secure and most likely require an extra connector.

Can any of you advise me of other ways, or ways you would do this?

- **Any way to program a C# program that acts as a web-service on my linux mySQL Server? Where should I look/search to learn more about this. Is it called something special? Or maybe its not done in C#?**
- **Should I program a php script that accepts HTTP SEND/GET requests from my C# Desktop client?**
- **Any other way?**

What way is most 'professional' in the real world? Trying to learn on my own! :D

FORMAT:

- Windows Desktop: client programmed in C# That retrieves temp data and needs to send to server
- Linux Server: Runs Apache and mySQL Server with a database already setup. Closed to outside Connections

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to set up a web service to communicate with your windows client. Directly connecting to mysql server is ok if they both resident in a same lan, but if not, for example your windows client is running on some laptop travelling everywhere or even the mysql server permits local incoming connection only, your should set up a web service. Also the http connection can usually go through firewalls while connections over other ports are blocked.

php is a good way to do this. Since you are learning c#, you may want to use c# to do the server side programming as well, so why not give a try of mono?

Answer (score 1):

Directly exposing a MySQL Server to the internet is strongly dicouraged, Additionally this gives you a rather coarse-grained set of access rights, that might not be enough for your application, so running some sort of server app is the right way to go.

- With mono you can run a lot of .Net (and thus C#) based code on a Linux server just fine. Rule of thumb is: If it doesn't have a Winforms GUI and no P/Invoke it will work just fine. Ofcourse this needs mono on the server, which is not given on most commercial hosts.
- Running the server in PHP makes it a lot more portable, but has a performance overhead. Additionally it doesn't allow for some of your busines logic objects to be implemented in a DLL assembly and used on both sides.
- As for the protocol: Chose your poison. Rule of thumb again is, that predefined protocols such as SOAP tend to need a bit more work (and more learning in the first go), but on the long term tend to be more robust.

For your special use-case I'd personally go with a quick PHP based solution where the protocol is just a simple GET with a few parameters, one being the temperature(s) and the others authenticating the client.

Comment: Thanks :) Just would like to note that I am wanting to send about 300 potential transmissions twice a day, probably about the same time. Ill include your advice on eventing only if it changes. So would PHP still suffice? Still going to look at mono tomorrow. Just wanted a direction on where to start research tomorrow.

Comment: 300 values of 5 digits each is 1500 bytes payload, say less than 4K with JSON and packaging - I don't see a problem with performance arising in PHP at all. Even a query string of "temp1=123.456&temp2=234.567&..." is more than good enough. Might want to use POST though.

Answer (score 0):

If the temperature sensor generates events, then I would 'push' the data from the Windows box to the Linux box - this will save the latter checking often and finding no updates. However if you are just taking temperature samples, I would 'pull' the data from the Linux machine. Either way, if you want to use HTTP you will need a web service on either side.

Alternatively, you could just connect to your MySQL database remotely from C#, and write the data directly (no web service would then be required). That might be the quickest way to get this working.

The 'which is professional' question is subjective - all three options above are fine. Just make the code clear and concise :)

Comment: You could use the fat client to change the sensor's MO from poll to event: Just poll it locally and only if the reading changes push it to the server.